# replace/remove text (sed) by a file

Tags: sed, cat

I want to replace/remove text all files by a file.

```
$ echo "_uU_%UHY%^GSSD$%GWRW$T#wf4werwefF$fW#$wfdd%6blahblahblah" > pattern.txt
$ sudo grep -rl "_uU" . | xargs sed -ie s/$(cat pattern.txt)//g
```

but, my command not working. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It have to remove `-e` flag.

```
$ echo "_uU_%UHY%^GSSD$%GWRW$T#wf4werwefF$fW#$wfdd%6blahblahblah" > pattern.txt
$ sudo grep -rl "_uU" . | xargs sed -i s/$(cat pattern.txt)//g
```